# What is meant by "got jumped"?

Tags: phrase-usage, phrase-meaning, phrases

From: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/96270/48426

> I ***got jumped*** with a couple of my friends one night.
>   ...
>   The next night, when we went to the house of the guys who ***had jumped*** us, the cops showed up just as we did, and one of the officers beat me senseless with his flashlight.

What is meant by "got jumped" and "had jumped"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the [American Heritage Dictionary of the English Language](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/jump) in this context applies the definition #3, as verb:

> 3. Slang To spring upon in sudden attack; assault or ambush: Muggers jumped him in the park.

So it means **I got attacked**.

As for the **had jumped**, it is the past perfect which expresses that the action was made before another past event, that is **we went**.

Answer (score 2):

In informal English, you use get instead of "be" to form passives. the verb jump  also means to attack suddenly in informal English. I got jumped with a couple of my friends one means that I was suddenly attacked along with a couple of my friends one night.

Who had jumped us means who had attacked us.